# Override RedirecToAction method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, redirecttoaction

Is there a way to extend the RedirectToAction method on mvc 5 for accepts masterName parameter. I'm looking for something like this:

```
RedirectToAction(actionName: "Index", controllerName: controllerName, masterName: "_Layout");
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Yes, it is ;) and seriously: It is not "do it fo me" forum. Paste some code and show others that you have began doing it by yourself

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I always trying to do everything by my own! But when all my possibles solutions not accomplish my goals, I start doing a research, I've more than a week working on this, doing extensions methods and other possibles solutions, but did not work. Sorry for my question if is bad writing it was a pressure moment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass route values.

```
return RedirectToAction(actionName: "Index", controllerName: controllerName,  new {masterName = "_Layout"});
```

The action method should have a parameter with name masterName. This parameter will then receive the value given here. You can then inside the controller action pass on the parameter to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index(string masterName)
{
    // Other code
    return View("Index", masterName);
}
```

Comment: I did this before and it work! But with some views override the div where the partial view is loaded. Now I'm working with this extension method, I'm trying to inject the layout with that

`public static RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<TRedirectController>(
                this Controller controller,
                Expression<Action<TRedirectController>> action,
                object routeValues = null)
            where TRedirectController : Controller
        {
            return GetRedirectFromExpression<TRedirectController>(action, routeValues);
        }`